# Hibernate: on delete cascade action for join table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a many-to-many relation between two entities 'menu_groups' and 'pages' as follows

```
    public class MenuGroup {
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
        @JoinTable(name = "menu_group_pages",schema="live",    
                  joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="menu_groups_id"),
                  inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="pages_id"))
        private Set<Page> pages = new HashSet<Page>();
    }

    public class Page {
       @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="pages", 
                   cascade={CascadeType.MERGE})

       private Set<MenuGroup> menuGroups = new HashSet<MenuGroup>();
    }
```

As you could see there is a join table which has two fk: menu_groups_id and pages_id. Now I want to add on delete cascade action for fk 'pages_id' in this join table. For a normal table, the statement is something like

```
    @OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
```

How could I do this for a join table? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to manually set the cascade options in the database and then just call remove on a managed Page object to remove it from the link table.

The OnDelete annotation should have generated the cascade options in the DB but it does not seem to work for ManyToMany ([HHH-4404](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4404))

On the other hand, if you would like to avoid making any schema changes, then you would just have to remove the association between the MenuGroup and Page. In your PageDAO (or whatever abstraction you use) you could have a remove method that removes the associations:

```
public void remove(Page page) {
    for(MenuGroup menuGroup : page.getMenuGroups()){
        menuGroup.getPages().remove(page);
    }
    session.remove(page);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to just set the CascadeType in your ManyToMany annotations to include `CascadeType.Remove` as well. You might be able to do `CascadeType.All` if it fits in with your data model. Either of these should cascade the deletes to both the Page\ManuGroup table as well as the join tables.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. If I set CascadeType.Remove in class Page, then when I delete a page, the corresponding menu group will be deleted too. When I delete a Page, I want only the relation in the join table to be deleted, but not the MenuGroup entity. That's why I did not use CascadeType.REMOVE. Any suggestion about that